# ASP.NET Menu control and Safari 4.0.3

Tags: c#, asp.net, safari, menu

So I'm using a Menu control on my page, and it has dynamic items that should drop down when you hover over a menu item.  This works in all browsers except for Safari 4.0.3.

I've looked around and there seem to be several solutions to this problem:

1. Add this code to the Page_Load event:

```
    if (Request.UserAgent.IndexOf("AppleWebKit") > 0)
    {
        Request.Browser.Adapters.Clear();
    }
```

2. Add this code to the Page_PreInit event:

   ```
   if (Request.UserAgent.IndexOf("AppleWebKit") > 0)
   {
       this.ClientTarget = "uplevel";
   }
   ```
3. Add a browser file like in this thread: [Link to thread](http://dashcommerce.org/forums/p/1593/5591.aspx)

Well I've tried all of those, and none of them seem to work.

I should mention that this did use to work in older versions of Safari using option #2.  But it's not working for me with the newest version of Safari.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried adding ClientTarget="uplevel" in the actual @Page directive?

Comment: Yes, that didn't fix it either.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [CSSAdapters version](http://www.asp.net/CSSAdapters/Menu.aspx) of the Menu? It produces much cleaner, semantic HTML and should be easier to style, too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your .browser file:

```
<browsers>
    <browser refID="Safari">
        <controlAdapters>
           <adapter controlType="System.Web.UI.WebControls.Menu" adapterType="" />
        </controlAdapters>
    </browser>
</browsers>
```

(from the top of my head, so exact syntax might be wrong)

The key is `<browser refID="Safari">`.